# Windows 10 File Explorer: FLAC files taking longer to appear the first time their folder is opened

Tags: windows-10, shell, windows-explorer, flac

Microsoft did something to file explorer (Windows shell) a while ago (I think it started with the Fall Creators Update) that causes an incredibly annoying delay when opening a folder containing FLAC files for the first time. After the folder has been opened once, the files populate instantly from then on.

After some investigation I guess Microsoft updated a shell extension to read metadata (id3 tags etc) from media files that causes the delay with flac. Also there is something called: Microsoft Media Feature Pack. I checked and I have this feature automagically installed, I think it came with the Fall Creators Update but not sure of that)

My question is: Has anyone else noticed this, or have any idea on how to fix it? I already disabled Cortana, this was not the problem. The problem appears only with flac files.